# Create Insert query with null value in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, insert, null

I create insert query for `Organization` table.

```
select 'Insert into Organizations(Name, IndustryId, ContactPerson, Email, Website, LocationId, ContactNumber, Mobilenumber) values(''' + 
       IsNull(Nameofthecompany, 'NULL') + ''',' + 
       Isnull(IndustryType, 'NULL') + ',''' +
       Isnull(Nameofthepersonresponsibleforrecruitment, 'NULL') + ''', ''' +
       Isnull(EmailId, 'NULL') + ''', ''' +
       Isnull(websiteaddress, 'NULL') + ''',' +
       Isnull(Location, 'NULL') + ',' +
       Isnull(PhoneNumber, 'NULL') + ',' +
       Isnull(MobileNumber, 'NULL') + ')' 
from Organization
```

Here I have the result set

```
Insert into Organizations(Name, IndustryId, ContactPerson, Email, Website, LocationId, ContactNumber, Mobilenumber)
values('username', industry, 'Name', 'NULL', 'NULL', place, NULL, 999999999)
```

I don't want the NULL value within quotes. If I remove the quotes means I get error. Please Help me find out the problem..

Comment: What is the error? Perhaps those columns are not nullable!

Comment: Well, what **else** do you want to have instead of `'NULL'` ? Just replace those with whatever you want to add .....

Comment: Show me your column definition. You can only insert `Null` if your column `allow Null`

Comment: show us the table structure of table `Organizations`.

Comment: I want instead of 'Null' show my resultset NULL.

Comment: Is your `resultset` a part of an application or procedure? If so, what programming language are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a value is NULL, then adding it to a string will produce a NULL.
This allows us to add the quotes in the ISNULL check and just produce NULL in the true value of the check, producing the correct syntax for nulls or not nulls as necessary.

```
select 'Insert into Organizations(Name, IndustryId, ContactPerson, Email, Website, LocationId, ContactNumber, Mobilenumber) values(' + 
       IsNull(''''+Nameofthecompany+'''', 'NULL') + ', ' + 
       Isnull(''''+IndustryType+'''', 'NULL') + ', ' +
       Isnull(''''+Nameofthepersonresponsibleforrecruitment+'''', 'NULL') + ', ' +
       Isnull(''''+EmailId+'''', 'NULL') + ', ' +
       Isnull(''''+websiteaddress+'''', 'NULL') + ', ' +
       Isnull(''''+Location+'''', 'NULL') + ', ' +
       Isnull(PhoneNumber, 'NULL') + ', ' +
       Isnull(MobileNumber, 'NULL') + ')' 
from Organization
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use `NULL` (as a literal - not a string) for your NULL values, then the creation of the `INSERT` statement gets a lot more complicated; if the value is `NULL`, then you need to add the literal `NULL` **without** a leading and trailing `'`.

For each column where you want to do this, you'll need to use a `CASE` statement - something like this:

```
select 'INSERT INTO Organizations(.....) ' + 
       'VALUES(' + 
       CASE 
           WHEN NameOfTheCompany IS NOT NULL 
              THEN '''' + NameOfTheCompany + ''', '
              ELSE 'NULL, ' 
       END + 
       CASE 
           WHEN IndustryType IS NOT NULL 
              THEN '''' + IndustryType + ''', '
              ELSE 'NULL, ' 
       END +
       ..... and so on ......
       + ')'
```

... and so on, for each column you need this `CASE` statement ....

Comment: bizarrely this seems to be the only bit of information about how to insert null deliberately I could find online!  Suppose it's just assumed knowledge